# Rails route update without member id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

My application is based off subdomains such as:

```
http://mylawfirm.resispsalaw.com
```

I need the following url to be a PUT on the current firm resource. I have the following in my routes:

```
...
constraints(Subdomain) do
  scope "/firm/" do
    put '/', action: :update, controller: :firm, as: "firm"
    ...
```

But when I get the `firm_path(@firm)` in my view I get the following:

```
/firm.test1
```

How can I get the `firm_path(@firm)` to return:

```
/firm
```

`rake routes` returns the following:

```
...
firm PUT    /firm(.:format)     firm#update
...
```

Comment: How are you linking to it in your view? Using just `firm_path`? Also what is the relevant output of `rake routes`?

Comment: Updated the post with the relevant rake routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your routing seems to be setup such that there is only a single `Firm` resource for the app, you need not pass an instance of `Firm` to `firm_path` and should simply do:

```
firm_path
```

Comment: Yup. You can tell from `rake routes`' output because it's just `/firm(.format)`, not `/firm/:id/(.format)`, so it doesn't need any parameters to create the URL.